# Ampersand in math in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, context

I'm afraid this is fairly obvious and has been asked many times, but I could not find the answer. I am having trouble getting an ampersand in a displayed formula in ConTeXt. I tried the obvious `\&`, and it seems fine outside math, i.e. this works:

```
\starttext
$\Pr$ (A \& B)
\stoptext
```

but this does not:

```
\starttext
\startformula
\Pr (A \& B)
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

(and using an unescaped '&' fails as well, unsurprisingly). Of course I could use `\wedge` or the word "and", but if at all possible I'd rather use an ampersand.

Comment: What do you mean, with you sent it too soon?

Comment: I don't know Context, but in Latex, I would advise using the `amsmath` package and `\text{\&}`. Maybe you can adapt it to the Context syntax.

Comment: Here's a workaround: `\appendtoks\def\&{\text{\letterampersand}}\to\everymathematics`

Comment: Take a look at the `\with` symbol from [the cmll font](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cmll) - that is an ampersand figure that has been adapted from the Computer Modern ampersand for use in maths mode.  If you like that, @Marco's trick together with a font import is what you need.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Done!

Comment: @Marco Cool, this works - and honestly I would never have been able to find it out by myself. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I will definitely have a look. For now, Marco's solution seems to work fine. Thanks all the same for the suggestion.

Comment: @T.Verron Thanks! Your solution works as well. As a matter of fact it seeems that just using `text{\&}` works (i.e., no need to `\usemodule[amsmath]`, apparently).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default there is no such command in math mode. However, you can switch to
text mode where `\&` is available:

```
\starttext
  \startformula
    A \text{\&} B
  \stopformula
\stoptext
```

If you use `\asciimode` you don't even need the backslash:

```
\asciimode
\starttext
  \startformula
    A \text{&} B
  \stopformula
\stoptext
```

To avoid wrapping the ampersand in `\text` add the following code to your
document. It redefines `\&` for both, inline and display math.

```
\appendtoks
  \def\&{\text{\letterampersand}}
\to\everymathematics

\starttext
  \startformula
    A \& B
  \stopformula

  \math{C \& D}

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which is a very usefull tool when you are looking for a special symbol.
This way, I found the `cmll` package, containing the `\with`-command.
I tried it in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{cmll}
\begin{document}
\[A \with B\]
\end{document}
```

and for me it worked well. I hope this works as well in ConTeX.

Comment: It needs to be a ConTeXt solution.

Comment: @percusse There is a long-standing agreement that we can have answers illustrating how other formats would tackle an issue. They are mainly ConTeXt answer to LaTeX questions, but the same idea applies in reverse.

Comment: @JosephWright Sure I didn't mean that the answer is not suitable. It was a reminder but maybe not in a well-constructed comment.

Comment: `cmll` has several other useful symbols, not just for linear logic (its titular purpose). Its automatic support for `eulervm` is a very nice touch. As an aside, I had to install `cmll` manually, but it wasn't difficult to do so.